Is it correct to use a comma before a yes or no at the end of an answer sentence instead of a period?
When you ask someone

Do you like ice cream?

They might respond by repeating the question words in their answer, like this:

Yes, I do.

Often, though, people reverse the order of the above answer, instead responding with

I do, yes.

Or maybe

I do. Yes.

When putting the "yes" first, if I'm not mistaken, the choice of comma vs. period depends on the repetition of the question words.  So, for example, the following would all be grammatically correct answers to "Do you like ice cream?":

Yes, I do.
Yes. I love it.
No; cake is better.
No. Please go away.

The "yes last" format seems more common in response to a question that presumes the answer.  For example,

So you do like ice cream?


I do, yes. / I do. Yes.

But which one is correct? Does it depend on the repetition of the question words, too? For example, would a response constraining the scope of the question with a qualifier, such as

Chocolate ice cream, yes.

be more (or less) incorrect than repeating the question words:

I do, yes.

Or is all of this just a stylistic choice, similar to my work's style guide leaving off the comma after "or" or "so" at the beginning of a sentence, as in

So you do like ice cream?

Instead of Microsoft Word's preference,

So, you do like ice cream?

Of course, I realize that "stylistic choice" can be an excuse to wave away almost any grammar rule. But since I've been unable to find any such rule to wave away, I thought I'd ask.
(Also, note that this ending "yes" is different from the tagged-on "yes", as in

You like ice cream, yes?

which has been addressed on this site many times.)

Punctuation of appended sentence fragments / sentence substitutes and introductory elements is very flexible. Assuming no loss of clarity ensues, and not adding or omitting pause signals ridiculously, use a comma (or a full stop) or zero punctuation to reflect how you'd like it to sound. For instance, << So, you do like ice cream?  >> **or** << So you do like ice cream? >> BUT NOT << You like ice cream  yes? >>

You need to distinguish punctuation in formal documents like court transcripts from informal things like text messages; with fiction and screenplays/scripts coming somewhere between. Try searching appropriate types of texts on Google Books or other search, since this looks like it's going to be closed. I'd guess comma is usual but much like buying shoes for a dog, it depends on the size of the paws.
